# SmartDeviceException - Class not registered when deploying UAP to device

Tags: xamarin, uwp, visual-studio-2017, windows-10-universal

When pressing start with "Device" selected for the first time, I get...

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     DEP0001: Unexpected Error: SmartDeviceException - Class not
>   registered [0x80131500]   UWP

What does this mean?

Which class is not registered?

The device is a Nokia Lumia 830. I recently upgraded it to Windows 10. It's running 10.0.14393.1770.

The app is targeting 16299, with minimum 10586. I've tried upgrading the phone, but I think it installed 14393 twice in a row.

I've tried reinstalling Visual Studio 2017.

Developer mode is switched on on the phone and the dev machine.

Comment: It is a deployment error, it couldn't get the app downloaded and activated on the device.  "Class not registered" is the universally vague error message for "a component is supposed to be installed but I can't find it".  With the standard hangup that it doesn't tell you exactly which component that might be.  All it has is a number.  You'll want to make sure that it isn't your app, it uses this error code as well, ensure it runs correctly in the emulator.  You are then down to a VS install mishap, the kind that requires spinning the repair/reinstall wheel of fortune.

Comment: Windows Home, so no simulator unfortunately.

Comment: That's like bringing a knife to a gun-fight, isn't it?  Hard to help you, try testing a "hello world" app.

Comment: lol. I did. Doesn't work with a native UAP app.